# Updating a paper on arXiv that was accepted by a non-open access journal

Tags: journals, arxiv, preprint

I have uploaded a paper on ArXiv a few months ago, and then submitted it to a non-open access journal. After appropriate revisions, the paper has been accepted by the journal, and will be published in the future. At the moment I would like to replace the old version of my paper on ArXiv with the current one that has been accepted by the journal. The journal’s guidelines are as follows:

> On a noncommercial free-access preprint server such as arXiv:
> The right to:
>
> 1. Post the preprint prior to submission and/or acceptance for publication by AIP Publishing.
> 2. Post the AM immediately after acceptance by AIP Publishing.
> 3. Update with the VOR 12 months after publication.
>
> (An appropriate credit line must be included that references the full citation for the published paper, along with a link to the VOR on AIP Publishing’s site.)

I have a few questions:

1. What do *AM* and *VOR* abbreviations mean?
2. Where do I add the credit line? On the research paper itself? On the front page at the bottom? Or elsewhere? How can I reference “the full citation for the published paper with a link...” at this stage if it hasn't been published yet?

I appreciate all feedback. Thanks.

Comment: AM = Accepted Manuscript, VOR = version of Record. Citation and link should be included once the VOR is ready (final publication). I understand the link should be on arkiv description, not on the paper itself, after all, you will have only a pdf of VOR

Comment: Please see [their web page](https://publishing.aip.org/authors/web-posting-guidelines) for VOR and AM.

Comment: If you have only a PDF of the VOR, then you should post the AM instead, despite anyone telling you the contrary. The arXiv doesn't take PDFs with no source unless really necessary, and journals also prefer their formatting and design not to appear on preprinted repositories.

Answer (score 3):

[The comments mostly answer this, but posting an answer as well for completeness]

**AM - Accepted Manuscript** (you may see the term AAM/Author's Accepted Manuscript or "postprint", as well). This is the version of the text at the point the journal accepts it - so with any revisions that were requested by reviewers, but before any final copyediting, formatting, etc.

**VOR - Version of Record** - the final published version from the journal with pretty formatting, pagination, and so on.

You should add the credit line (effectively a citation to the final version) to the arXiv landing page, but it's always a good idea to put it on the paper as well - perhaps a note on the first page to ensure that the reader has a handy reference for the correct citation.

The credit line should be to the published version (with DOI etc) but if this has not yet appeared, then something like "Accepted for publication in the *Journal of Widgets*, copyright the International Widget Research Society, posted with permission" will do - you can then update this as and when you have the correct details.

Comment: In math, what's typical is to add the "to appear" as a comment.  Then you can add the full citation when you know it without updating your post, but unfortunately many people don't.  I almost never see a note about "to appear" in the paper, but I like the idea.